# Make [gdpr] and [general-data-protection-regulation] tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[general-data-protection-regulation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-data-protection-regulation) has 6 questions and [gdpr](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdpr) has 2. It's easy to retag one to the other manually, however, new questions are likely to create the other tag again.

Therefore, I think it's easiest to just make them synonyms. It doesn't really matter which is a synonym of which, though [gdpr](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdpr) is more concise.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer [general-data-protection-regulation] as the main tag over the much shorter [gdpr]?

Comment: @yannis not really, could be the other way around as well.